# Angular-UI Calendar : Not getting unique id when adding an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm developing an application in which I want to populate the calendar with users appointment. Hence for that I've integrated angular-ui-calendar in my code.

I'm able to successfully add the events and also able to get the unique ids generated by Angular-UI Calendar. But issue is coming when I'm jumping to particular date from different view using the following method.

```
$scope.gotoCalendar = function(date) {
     Events.get().then(function(response) {
         $scope.events.splice(0);
         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
             $scope.events.push(response[i]);
         }

         uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
         $state.go('booking.calendar');
     });
 };
```

Now when I try to add another event, angular-ui-calendar is assigning the same id.

In below given screenshot, `0th item and 3rd item` got the same id. Now when user tries to update an event, events having the same id are also getting updated.

[image]

**Here is my controller code**

```
    $scope.addEvent = function(appointment) {
     var endDate = appointment.endDate;
     var endTime = appointment.endTime;
     var endTimeHours = endTime.getHours();
     var endTimeMinutes = endTime.getMinutes();


     var startDate = appointment.startDate;
     var startTime = appointment.startTime;
     var startTimeHours = startTime.getHours();
     var startTimeMinutes = startTime.getMinutes();

     var formattedEndDate = new Date(moment.utc(setHoursMinutes(endDate, endTimeHours, endTimeMinutes)).format());
     var formattedStartDate = new Date(moment.utc(setHoursMinutes(startDate, startTimeHours, startTimeMinutes)).format());

     if (formattedStartDate.getTime() >= formattedEndDate.getTime()) {
         $scope.showAlert('Cannot save Event', 'Start date must be before the end date');
         return;
     }


     Events.add(appointment);

     Events.get().then(function(response) {
         $scope.events.splice(0);

         console.log('[addEvent]response : :', response);

         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
             $scope.events.push(response[i]);
         }

         $scope.myAppointments = angular.copy($scope.events);
     });
     $scope.appointment = { title: '', startDate: '', startTime: '', endDate: '', endTime: '' };
     $scope.closeModal();

 };

 $scope.gotoCalendar = function(date) {
     Events.get().then(function(response) {
         $scope.events.splice(0);
         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
             $scope.events.push(response[i]);
         }

         uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar'].fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
         $state.go('booking.calendar');
     });
 };


 /* Change View */
 $scope.changeView = function(view, calendar) {
     console.info('changeView 1', $scope.events);

     Events.get().then(function(response) {
         $scope.events.splice(0);

         console.log('changeView [response] : :', response);

         for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
             $scope.events.push(response[i]);
         }


         uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView', view);

     });
 };


 /* Change View */
 $scope.renderCalender = function(calendar) {
     console.info('Rendering Calendar...');
     if (uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]) {
         uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
     }
 };



 $scope.OnDayClick = function(date, jsEvent, view) {

     var formattedDate = new Date(date);
     $scope.appointment = {
         startDate: formattedDate,
         startTime: formattedDate
     };

     $scope.appointment.minEndDate = moment($scope.appointment.startDate).format().split('T')[0];
     $scope.openModal();
 };




 /* event sources array*/
 $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

 /* config object */
 $scope.uiConfig = {

 calendar: {
     height: 450,
     editable: true,
     defaultView: "agendaDay",
     ignoreTimezone: true,
     eventDurationEditable: false,
     defaultDate: new Date(),
     allDay: false,
     allDayDefault: false,
     allDaySlot: false,
     timezone: 'local',
     eventOverlap: false,
     header: {
         left: 'title',
         center: '',
         right: 'today prev,next'
     },
     dayClick: $scope.OnDayClick,
     eventClick: $scope.OnEventClick,
     eventDrop: $scope.OnDrop,
     eventRender: $scope.eventRender
 }
```

So, how do I resolve this issue? Hope I'm able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an exact answer for you, we were having the same issues with a project for school.  After much frustration we modified some code in `fullcalendar.js` (angular-ui-calendar dependency) which resolved the issue for getting unique IDs, however we still had issues with dragging and dropping and duplicate IDs and had to disable editing.

**Original code:**

```
out._id = input._id || (input.id === undefined ? '_fc' + eventGUID++ : input.id + '');
```

**Modified code:**

```
if (!input._id && input.id) {
    input._id = ++eventGUID * -1;
}

out._id = input._id || (input.id === undefined ? '_fc' + eventGUID++ : eventGUID++);
```

I ran out of time to come up with a more robust solution, but it served its purpose.